# How to save an Emgu `Image<Bgr, Byte> frame` in a memory stream as JPEG?

Tags: .net, opencv, computer-vision, emgucv

How can I save an Emgu `Image<Bgr, Byte> frame` in a memory stream as JPEG?

Answer (score 5):

You have two options the first is the native EMGU images.save("filename"); method however the quality is not great and lossy. The best method is to use the following c# method.

This is the function is saveJpeg(SaveFile.FileName, img.ToBitmap(), 100);. Based on the method saveJpeg(string path, Bitmap img, long quality).

```
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

private void saveJpeg(string path, Bitmap img, long quality)
{
    // Encoder parameter for image quality

    EncoderParameter qualityParam = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, quality);

    // Jpeg image codec
    ImageCodecInfo jpegCodec = this.getEncoderInfo("image/jpeg");

    if (jpegCodec == null)
    return;

    EncoderParameters encoderParams = new EncoderParameters(1);
    encoderParams.Param[0] = qualityParam;

    img.Save(path, jpegCodec, encoderParams);
}

private ImageCodecInfo getEncoderInfo(string mimeType)
{
    // Get image codecs for all image formats
    ImageCodecInfo[] codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();

    // Find the correct image codec
    for (int i = 0; i < codecs.Length; i++)
    if (codecs[i].MimeType == mimeType)
    return codecs[i];
    return null;
}
```

hope this helps,

Cheers,

Chris

Comment: jpeg, even with a quality of 100, is lossy.  
png is lossless.

Answer (score 3):

The quickest and dirtiest way with good quality and high-speed is:

C#

```
yourImage.toBitmap().Save("filename.png");
```

VB

```
YourImage.ToBitmap().Save("filename.png")
```

Comment: `ToBitMap()` enforces 8-bit precision in Emgu (so, better name would be `ToBytemap()`). For higher precision use `Image.Save("filename.png");`

Answer (score 1):

All the methods mentioned here are good but here I'm sharing another quick and short method which works good for me. First bring the Emgu.CV.**Image<,>** to System.Drawing.**Image** then use **Save** method to save JPEG in a Memory Stream.

Add references:

```
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using Emgu.CV;
```

Type this code:

```
MemoryStream MyMemoryStream = new MemoryStream();

Image MySystemImage = MyEmguImage.ToBitmap();
MySystemImage.Save(MyMemoryStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Regards